# Asking a Question about Fonts for Web Development

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I would like to ask a question about converting fonts for use on a web site.

The question will involve the existence of suitable software, as well as a question on the legality or suitability of the license.

Where is the best place to ask this?

**Edit:**

This is the actual question (I don’t expect it to be answered here, of course):

I would like to convert a font which uses the Open Font License to `WOFF` for use on a web site. My understanding is that this conversion probably contravenes the license. However, I have also read

> Please note that most WOFF conversion tools and online services do not meet the two requirements listed above

— https://theleagueof.github.io/licenses/ofl-faq.html (section 2.2)

This suggests that *some* tools do meet the requirements.

Can anybody suggest any software tools which meet this requirement? Preferably Open Source, and available on Linux or Macintosh.

Answer (score 5):

[Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) looks like a good option. Their [fonts tag](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fonts) states:

> Questions about matching fonts, using fonts together, manipulating fonts, font selection and font purchase and usage rights. Please use a more specific tag if available.

That said, 'the existence of suitable software' looks like a recommendation question and those are usually not a good fit for *any* Stack Exchange website (except [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), but they have strict [guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) for questions). So it could be that you have to split your question in two pieces.